# Background not appearing with customized pseudo-popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having a problem with the background of a pseudo-popup. I use jQuery (1.7) and [this tutorial](http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/) to create popups in my website. Basically I have two preformatted divs (one semi-opaque to hide the rest of the page and the other - with an image as the background - containing the actual popup, with the CSS already loaded in the page) that aren't displayed and that I show when I need them to display the popup, with additional fillings for the second div (to have different popups).

My problem is that the background of the popup doesn't load, and that I end up with only the semi-opaque background and the content of the popup. However, if disable/enable the CSS background property in the console, the background reappears as it should have in the first place.

This problem has appeared relatively recently not after any modification to the actual popup function, so I don't really know where it might come from. It can't be an issue of the background image not yet loaded since it is already there when the page has loaded.

Relevant pieces of code:

HTML:

```
<div id='popup_container'></div>
<div id='backgroundPopup'></div>
```

CSS:

```
#backgroundPopup{
    display:none;
    position: fixed;
    _position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6*/
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #000000;
    border: 1px solid #cecece;
    z-index: 1;  
}

#popup_container{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    _position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6*/
    height: 526px;
    width: 718px;
    background: url(http://cdn.mojogroups.com/Layout/popup.png) no-repeat !important;
    z-index: 2;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Javascript:

```
//When initializing the page
$(document).ready(function(){

//[...]

popup = new Popup();
popup.initialize();

}

function Popup(){
var popupStatus = 0;



function togglePopup(){
    if(popupStatus == 0){
        centerPopup();
        loadPopup();
    }
    else
        disablePopup();
}

function loadPopup(){
    if(popupStatus == 0){
        $('#backgroundPopup').css({
            "opacity": "0.7"
        });
        $('#backgroundPopup').fadeIn("fast");
        $('#popup_container').fadeIn("fast");
        $('body').scrollTop(0);
        $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
        popupStatus = 1;
    }
}

this.disablePopup = function(){
    if(popupStatus == 1){
        $('#backgroundPopup').fadeOut("fast");
        $('#popup_container').fadeOut("fast");
        $('#popup_container').empty();
        $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
        popupStatus = 0;
    }
}

function centerPopup(){
    var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;  
    var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var popupHeight = $('#popup_container').height();
    var popupWidth = $('#popup_container').width();


    $('#popup_container').css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": windowHeight/2 - popupHeight/2,
        "left": windowWidth/2 - popupWidth/2
    });

    $('#backgroundPopup').css({
        "height": windowHeight
    });
}

this.initialize = function(){
    $('#backgroundPopup').click(function(){
        popup.disablePopup();
    });

    $(document).keypress(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==27)
            popup.disablePopup();
    });
}

this.contacts = function(){
    //Fill the popup container...
        centerPopup();
    loadPopup();
    popupDiv.fadeIn('fast');
}
```

What could it be?

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT: the site (early version) can be found [here](http://pionid.com:8080)

UPDATE: At some point I thought it was due to the opacity attribute added by the loadPopup() function, so I removed that part of the code; but the bug still appears (although maybe less frequently, but it's hard to be sure since it was transient in the first place).

Comment: It would be nice to actually see your code or the page that is having issues. It's hard to tell what the problem could be without actually seeing the code.

Comment: Working code in jsfiddle.net would be super helpful. Also, is this in every browser, or just a specific browser?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. It seems to be only on chrome (latest version). I've added a link to the website in construction.

Comment: What should we click on to trigger the pop-up/modal? Also, post the relevant excerpt of your code *here*, otherwise once your site's fixed the question doesn't make any sense (since it'll just link to a fixed page).

Comment: I posted the code excerpt. To trigger the popup, you should be logged (sorry, right now it's only done through Facebook) and click on either the "new group" button in the header or on one of the three vertically aligned buttons in the top-right corner of the main container.

Answer (score 0):

I know its not the ways to as query in answer but i we cant add images in comments so i m asking here. I have just gone through with your problem, what i m getting is you cann see the below screen shot. Is it correct output or not.[image]

Comment: It is more or less correct, although you probably haven't run "centerpopup" if it is placed here.